# Firestore query not fetching latest data

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I have made a route guard in Angular, that checks for a certain value in firestore before allowing access to said route.

The component is routed to once a HTTP cloud function has completed. This cloud function creates an object in a firestore document called `agreement`, which the route then listens to the status within this object, to decide whether to allow access or not. The issue we are having though, is that maybe 9/10 times, the guard seems to think that the `agreement` object does not exist in the document, and therefore throws an error. (Though I can see the agreement object there in firestore!).

I have logged the flow, and it correctly logs within the subscription, then within the guard, so I know that the HTTP function is completing before trying to route and calling the guard class.

This is the guard:

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    this.tenancyOffer$ = this._tenancyOffer.getTenancyOfferById(route.params.offerId).get({source: 'server'})).valueChanges();
    
    return this.tenancyOffer$.pipe(
      map((tenancyOffer) => {
        if (tenancyOffer.status === 'incomplete'
          && tenancyOffer.agreement.status === 'incomplete') {
          return true;
        } else {
          this._router.navigate(['/' + Landlord.base, Landlord.manage.base, Landlord.manage.applications.base, route.params.propId, Landlord.manage.applications.summary, route.params.offerId]);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

GetTenancyOfferById:

```
this.tenancyOfferCollection = afs.collection<any>('tenancy_offers');

getTenancyOfferById(id: string) {
  return this.tenancyOfferCollection.doc(id);
}
```

the error is coming from this part: `tenancyOffer.agreement.status === 'incomplete'`, saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined.`

The HTTP function I'm calling is here, with the routing to this component in the subscribe:

```
  landlordAcceptReferences() {
    this.hasAcceptedRefs = true;
    this.processingAcceptRefs = true;
    this._references.landlordAcceptReferences(this.offerId).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.processingAcceptRefs = false;
      })
    ).subscribe(e => {
      console.log({e});
      this.dref.close();
      this._toastr.success(`You have accepted tenant references`);
      this._router.navigate(['../../', Landlord.manage.applications.agreement.base, this.offerId], {relativeTo: this._activatedRoute});
    }, () => this.hasAcceptedRefs = false);
  }
```

I made the response of the cloud function the entire firestore document, and that HAS the agreement object within it which is logged `console.log({e});`. I then log (AFTER) in the guard, the value of the document, and it does not exist, even though this is where I make another call to firestore?

Does anyone have any ideas why the `getTenancyOfferById(route.params.offerId)` function within the guard, is not returning the latest version of this document from firestore, even though the cloud function needs to end before routing in the subscription?

Comment: Can you show me your code of `this._tenancyOffer.getTenancyOfferById(route.params.offerId).get` ?

Comment: @N.F. I have added it into my question for you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess `this.tenancyOfferCollection = afs.collection<any>('tenancy_offers');` is defined somewhere in your service. If this is true, the collection will be loaded as soon as your application is loaded.

I recommend to store `tenancy_offers` values in your service and read it from your guard.

**Service:**

```
export class YourService {

  private tenancyOfferMap: Map<string, any> = new Map();

  constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
  ) {
    afs.collection<any>('tenancy_offers').snapshotChanges()
      .subscribe( actions => {
        actions.map( action => {
          this.tenancyOfferMap.set(action.payload.doc.id, action.payload.doc.data());
        });
      });
  }

  getTenancyOfferById(id: string) {
    return this.tenancyOfferMap.get(id);
  }

}
```

**Guard:**

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    const tenancyOffer = this.yourService.getTenancyOfferById(route.params.offerId);
    if (tenancyOffer.status === 'incomplete'
      && tenancyOffer.agreement.status === 'incomplete') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return this._router.navigate(['/' + Landlord.base, Landlord.manage.base, Landlord.manage.applications.base, route.params.propId, Landlord.manage.applications.summary, route.params.offerId]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the fact that your stream does not complete.

```js
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    this.tenancyOffer$ = this._tenancyOffer.getTenancyOfferById(route.params.offerId).get({source: 'server'})).valueChanges()
      .pipe(take(1)); // <-- ensure your stream completes in guards

    return this.tenancyOffer$.pipe(
      map((tenancyOffer) => {
        if (tenancyOffer && tenancyOffer.status === 'incomplete'
          && tenancyOffer.agreement.status === 'incomplete') {
          return true;
        } else {
          this._router.navigate(['/' + Landlord.base, Landlord.manage.base, Landlord.manage.applications.base, route.params.propId, Landlord.manage.applications.summary, route.params.offerId]);
          return false; // <-- always return something in guards
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Still having the same issue im afraid!

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `route.params.offerId` is filled with the right value?

Comment: It may be also helpful to share a sample of your data model/structure.